# Blurry text in windows 10 and youtube resolution is weird

Tags: windows-10, resolution

This is an example

[image]

and my YouTube resolution is like [this](https://ibb.co/r6q5B8d).

My monitor's resolution tells me 1280x1024 , everytime I try to change it, it's messed up, how to fix this?

Comment: If a Laptop, set the Display to Native resolution, then update BIOS, Chipset and Video drivers and restart, test

Comment: Its a PC, I just switched from win 7 to 10 today

Comment: Even so, make sure the PC graphics is set to the native Display resolution and be sure to do the BIOS and Video updates,  chipset if there is one.

Comment: Check also (in Settings > System > Display) that the Scale and Layout is set to the recommended percentage.